# KDE Plasma жрёт 5гб ОЗУ. Норм или нет?

Tags: linux, kde

[image: потребление ресурсов]

[image: сам рабочий стол]

Использую живые обои (плагин SmartER VideoWallpaper), тему Ompa-Dark-V2, оформление окна Shades-of-purple, оформление рабочего стола ChromeOsKDE, оформление приложений Breeze (по умолчанию), значки Magna-Dark-Icons, курсор мыши Radyzen, заставка Magna-Splash.

Вот информация про дистрибутив:

[image: дистрибутив]

> Потребление без этих параметров оформлений (полностью чистый KDE) занимает в ОЗУ всего 1гб

**Есть несколько вопросов:**

*1. Есть возможность оптимизировать потребление ресурсов, не убирая виджеты и всякие настройки оформления?*

*2. Если нет, то сущетсвует ли другое окружение рабочего стола, который не потребляет много ресурсов и на нём можно устанавливать темы?*

> да, я ОЗУдрочер

Comment: у меня гном шелл кушает 185 мегабайт

Comment: по поводу `htop`:: чтобы не захламлялся вывод можно убрать отображение пользовательских нитей(thr - threads) - `Shift+H` коих больше полутысячи, также дополнительно можно было бы оптимизировать верхнюю шапку убрав ненужное(swap) и сместив часть колонок(см. `F2`). По поводу самого потребления ресурсов - _"Любишь медок, люби и холодок"_, ну или _"Красота требует жертв"_ ;; на сколько видно у вас не тока проблема с потреблением памяти, на что в принципе можно закрыть глаза, но и утилизация 15-20% процессора в _пустую_  что может сказаться на отзывчивости самой системы.

Comment: Попробуйте убрать живые обои и посмотреть что будет, думаю они делают в потребление наибольший вклад.

Comment: @user501383, да! действительно, я поставил обычный чёрный фон (даже ставил картинку) и показатели пторебление ядер оказались на нуле). А про htop - спасибо, полезный совет. а поребление ОЗУ поменялось незначительно, но тоже пойдёт (c 4.27гб до ~3.20гб)

Comment: @eri, я не люблю гном :D

Comment: @user501383, перезагрузив ПК, потребление показывает 1гб

Comment: mate, xfce, lxde. Если на самом деле нужно не DE, а иксы с менеджером окон, то WindowMaker. Но, глядя на скриншоты, я бы сказал, что вы вовсе не на ОЗУ наяриваете :)